# Yii2 url config not working

Tags: yii2, url-routing, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

I'm using yii2 and i want url to be this way:
example: backend.dev/ads/browse/city/london

My code is this(backend/config/main.php):

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<city:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\d+>' => 
                               '<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

And my link is:

```
echo Html::a('<h4>'.$cities[$i].'</h4>', ['/ads/browse', 
             'city'=>$cities[$i]], ['class'=>'btn buttonCity']);
```

But the output is this: backend.dev/ads/browse?city=london
I want ? to disappear, help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Bizely**
I have to make these changes:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

change to:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

My carelessness!

Answer (score 1):

`\d+` means it expects number but you gave `london`.

Change

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

to

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<city:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

Comment: Thanks, how do i change it exactly?